# How to check whether all two objects' properties are equal, including derived ones?

Tags: c#, equals

Let's say I have these three classes:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int IdNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    // Constructor and methods.
}

class Employee : Person
{
    public byte SalaryPerHour { get; set; }
    public byte HoursPerMonth { get; set; }

    // Constructor and methods.
}

class Seller : Employee
{
    public short SalesGoal { get; set; }
    public bool MetSaleGoleLastYear { get; set; }

    // Constructor and methods.
}
```

I would implement `IEquatable<T>` like this:

```
public bool Equals(Person other)
{
    if (other == null) return false;
    return FirstName == other.FirstName
        && LastName == other.LastName
        && IdNumber == other.IdNumber
        && Address == other.Address;
}

public bool Equals(Employee other)
{
    if (other == null) return false;
    return FirstName == other.FirstName
        && LastName == other.LastName
        && IdNumber == other.IdNumber
        && Address == other.Address
        && SalaryPerHour == other.SalaryPerHour
        && HoursPerMonth == other.HoursPerMonth;
}

public bool Equals(Seller other)
{
    if (other == null) return false;
    return FirstName == other.FirstName
        && LastName == other.LastName
        && IdNumber == other.IdNumber
        && Address == other.Address
        && SalaryPerHour == other.SalaryPerHour
        && HoursPerMonth == other.HoursPerMonth
        && SalesGoal == other.SalesGoal
        && MetSaleGoleLastYear == other.MetSaleGoleLastYear;
}
```

Now, as you can see, the more a class is down the inheritance chain, the more properties I need to check. If for example, I inherit from a class someone else written, I also need to see the class code to find all of its properties, so I could use them to check value equality. It sounds strange to me. Isn't there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use base. Much shorter.

```
public bool Equals(Seller other)
{
    if (other == null) return false;
    return base.Equals(other)
    && SalesGoal == other.SalaryPerHour;
    && MetSaleGoleLastYear == other.HoursPerMonth;
}
```

Comment: This, nor the original code, handles the situation where `other != null` but one of the variables, e.g. `other.FirstName, == null`. Is this scenario possible?

Comment: If `other.FirstName == null`, `Equals` will return false, unless `this.FirstName == null` too.  I think that is correct behavior.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of the exception thrown when you try and access a variable of a null object but `other != null` is a sufficient check for this.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to John Wu's answer, here is the corrected complete solution :

```
public bool Equals(Person other)
{
    if (other == null) return false;
    return FirstName == other.FirstName
        && LastName == other.LastName
        && IdNumber == other.IdNumber
        && Address == other.Address;
}

public bool Equals(Employee other)
{
    if (other == null) return false;
    return base.Equals(other)
        && SalaryPerHour == other.SalaryPerHour // ; removed
        && HoursPerMonth == other.HoursPerMonth;
}

public bool Equals(Seller other)
{
    if (other == null) return false;
    return base.Equals(other)
        && SalesGoal == other.SalesGoal // SalaryPerHour;
        && MetSaleGoleLastYear == other.MetSaleGoleLastYear; //HoursPerMonth;
}
```